# Vertical alignment in \tabular environment with \chemfig

Tags: tables, chemfig, vertical

How can I vertically align my rows to the center of the molecules? This is my table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,  a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Perfluorinated carboxylic acids used for the sorption isotherm experiments in this study. PFCs correspond to the number of perfluorinated carbon units on the PFCA-chain.}
\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
\label{tab:PFCAs}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
PFCs & Name & Acronym & Structure & CAS \\ \midrule
& & & & \\
4 & Perfluoropentanoic acid  & PFPeA & \chemfig[atom style={scale=0.7}]{O=[:90](-[:30,,,1]OH)-[:150](-[:112.5]F)(-[:67.5]F)-[:210](-[:292.5]F)(-[:247.5]F)-[:150](-[:112.5]F)(-[:67.5]F)-[:210](-[:270]F)(-[:150]F)-[:210]F} & 2706-90-3 \\
& & & & \\
5   & Perfluorohexanoic acid & PFHxA  & \chemfig[atom style={scale=0.7}]{O=[:270](-[:330,,,1]OH)-[:210](-[:247.5]F)(-[:292.5]F)-[:150](-[:67.5]F)(-[:112.5]F)-[:210](-[:247.5]F)(-[:292.5]F)-[:150](-[:67.5]F)(-[:112.5]F)-[:210](-[:270]F)(-[:150]F)-[:210]F} & 307-24-4  \\
& & & & \\
6   & Perfluoroheptanoic acid & PFHpA  & \chemfig[atom style={scale=0.7}]{O=[:270](-[:330,,,1]OH)-[:210](-[:292.5]F)(-[:247.5]F)-[:150](-[:112.5]F)(-[:67.5]F)-[:210](-[:292.5]F)(-[:247.5]F)-[:150](-[:112.5]F)(-[:67.5]F)-[:210](-[:292.5]F)(-[:247.5]F)-[:150](-[:90]F)(-[:210]F)-[:150]F} & 375-85-9 \\
& & & & \\
7   & Perfluorooctanoic acid & PFOA  & \chemfig[atom style={scale=0.7}]{O=[:90](-[:30,,,1]OH)-[:150](-[:67.5]F)(-[:112.5]F)-[:210](-[:247.5]F)(-[:292.5]F)-[:150](-[:67.5]F)(-[:112.5]F)-[:210](-[:247.5]F)(-[:292.5]F)-[:150](-[:67.5]F)(-[:112.5]F)-[:210](-[:247.5]F)(-[:292.5]F)-[:150](-[:90]F)(-[:150]F)-[:210]F} & 335-76-2 \\
& & & & \\
8   & Perfluorononaoic acid  & PFNA  & \chemfig[atom style={scale=0.7}]{
           O% 2
     =[:90]% 1
              (
     -[:30,,,1]OH% 28
              )
    -[:150]% 3
              (
      -[:112.5]F% 26
              )
              (
       -[:67.5]F% 27
              )
    -[:210]% 4
              (
      -[:292.5]F% 24
              )
              (
      -[:247.5]F% 25
              )
    -[:150]% 5
              (
      -[:112.5]F% 22
              )
              (
       -[:67.5]F% 23
              )
    -[:210]% 6
              (
      -[:292.5]F% 20
              )
              (
      -[:247.5]F% 21
              )
    -[:150]% 7
              (
      -[:112.5]F% 18
              )
              (
       -[:67.5]F% 19
              )
    -[:210]% 8
              (
      -[:292.5]F% 16
              )
              (
      -[:247.5]F% 17
              )
    -[:150]% 9
              (
      -[:112.5]F% 14
              )
              (
       -[:67.5]F% 15
              )
    -[:210]% 10
              (
        -[:270]F% 11
              )
              (
        -[:210]F% 13
              )
    -[:150]F% 12
} & 375-95-1\\
& & & & \\
9   & Perfluorodecanoic acid  & PFDA  & \chemfig[atom style={scale=0.7}]{O=[:270](-[:330,,,1]OH)-[:210](-[:247.5]F)(-[:292.5]F)-[:150](-[:67.5]F)(-[:112.5]F)-[:210](-[:247.5]F)(-[:292.5]F)-[:150](-[:67.5]F)(-[:112.5]F)-[:210](-[:247.5]F)(-[:292.5]F)-[:150](-[:67.5]F)(-[:112.5]F)-[:210](-[:247.5]F)(-[:292.5]F)-[:150](-[:67.5]F)(-[:112.5]F)-[:210](-[:270]F)(-[:150]F)-[:210]F} & 335-67-1\\
& & & & \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

I get the following output:
[image: Output table]

Any tips will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\smash{\raisebox{5ex}}` should serve the purpose -- you could experiment with the `5ex` for variation

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Perfluorinated carboxylic acids used for the sorption isotherm experiments in this study. PFCs correspond to the number of perfluorinated carbon units on the PFCA-chain.}
\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
\label{tab:PFCAs}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
PFCs & Name & Acronym & Structure & CAS \\ \midrule
& & & & \\
\smash{\raisebox{5ex}{4}} & \smash{\raisebox{5ex}{Perfluoropentanoic acid}}  & \smash{\raisebox{5ex} {PFPeA}} & \chemfig[atom style={scale=0.7}]{O=[:90](-[:30,,,1]OH)-[:150](-[:112.5]F)(-[:67.5]F)-[:210](-[:292.5]F)(-[:247.5]F)-[:150](-[:112.5]F)(-[:67.5]F)-[:210](-[:270]F)(-[:150]F)-[:210]F} & \smash{\raisebox{5ex} {2706-90-3}} \\
& & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Using \smash\raisebox helped! Thank you so much for your help, I'm new to latex and have fiddled with making this table work for many days and finally it looks the way I want it to. Thanks again:)